# If $f(x,t)$ is continuous then $\int_{0}^{1}f(x,t)^p dx$ is continuous for any $p\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Suppose that $f(x,t)$, with $(x,t)\in [0,1]\times [0,+\infty)$, is continuous with respect to $t$ and with respect to $x$. Is it true that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x,t)^pdx$, with $p\in \mathbb{N}$, is continuous with respect to $t$?

My intuition is that, while the derivative operator diminishes the regularity, the integral operator preserves it (and even increases it), but I don't see how to prove this.

Comment: You need more hypothesis. If $f$ is bounded then the answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I got it. So, on each finite interval $[0,T]$, since $f$ is continuous then it is bounded. Thus, on each finite interval, the integral is continuous. So without assuming more than continuity, we have that the integral is continuous on each compact subset of $[0,+\infty)$. With boundedness, we have continuity on all $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @Galois A small remark here: you argument works assuming $f$ is jointly continuous in both $x$ and $t$ (or, more generally, if it is separately continuous in $x$ and $t$ but uniformly bounded when restricted to any compact domain). But the way your question is framed could be understood that you’re only asking about $f$ being separately continuous in $x$ and $t$ instead of jointly continuous. Under that weaker assumption the answer is actually no…

Comment: @Galois Consider, for example, $f(x, t) = \frac{2xt}{(x^2+t^2)^2}$ when $(x, t) \neq (0, 0)$ and $f(0, 0) = 0$. Then $f$ is separately continuous with respect to either $x$ or $t$, but not joint continuous. Furthermore, if you set $p = 1$, then a direct calculation shows that $\int_0^1 f(x,t)\, dx$ is actually not continuous in $t$: $\int_0^1 f(x,0)\, dx = 0$, but $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \int_0^1 f(x,t)\, dx = +\infty$.

Comment: I see yes, thank you for your clarification.